# "Read More" and "Read Less" script for text on ALL thumbnails, not just one

Tags: jquery, html

I need help getting the toggle script below to work for, "Read More" and "Read Less" feature for ALL thumbnails in the gallery, not just the first thumbnail. Each card can be packed with information including paragraphs, bullets, and links. And the page looks overwhelming that way, hence my use of the "Read More" and "Read Less" feature. As it stands, the script selects IDs, not classes and I think that's the problem (I found the script online).

Any thoughts on how to update the script to work for ALL thumbnails in the gallery?

My best guess is to call on a class name, but I imagine that would toggle ALL thumbnails at the same time, which is also no good.

Ideally, each thumbnail could "show more" and "show less" independently of the others.

```js
$("#toggle").click(function() {
  var elem = $("#toggle").text();
  if (elem == "Read More") {
    //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
    $("#toggle").text("Read Less");
    $("#text").slideDown();
  } else {
    //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
    $("#toggle").text("Read More");
    $("#text").slideUp();
  }
});
```

```css
#text{
  display:none;
}

a#toggle {
  color:#2095cf;
  margin:10px 0px 10px 0px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- CLASS CARD 1 -->
<!-- CLASS CARD 1 -->
<!-- CLASS CARD 1 -->
  <div class="class-card">
  <h2>Course Title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse felis eros, iaculis vel sem sed, aliquam pretium nunc. Nulla luctus arcu est, sed fermentum quam aliquam nec.</p>
  <!-- NOTE: '#text' wraps the expandable stuff -->
  <span id="text">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
      </ul>
      <p><strong>Pick a Time:</strong></p>
      <a class="black-button" href="#">Monday 7/23 @ 1PM &ndash; 3PM</a>
      <a class="black-button" href="#">Wednesday 7/24 @ 12PM &ndash; 2PM</a>
  </span><!--end text -->

  <!-- '#toggle' triggers the JQuery function -->
  <a id="toggle">Read More</a>

  </div><!-- end class-card -->





<!-- CLASS CARD 2 -->
<!-- CLASS CARD 2 -->
<!-- CLASS CARD 2 -->
  <div class="class-card">
  <h2>Course Title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse felis eros, iaculis vel sem sed, aliquam pretium nunc. Nulla luctus arcu est, sed fermentum quam aliquam nec.</p>
  <!-- NOTE: '#text' wraps the expandable stuff -->
  <span id="text">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
      </ul>
      <p><strong>Pick a Time:</strong></p>
      <a class="black-button" href="#">Monday 7/23 @ 1PM &ndash; 3PM</a>
      <a class="black-button" href="#">Wednesday 7/24 @ 12PM &ndash; 2PM</a>
  </span><!--end text -->

  <!-- '#toggle' triggers the JQuery function -->
  <a id="toggle">Read More</a>


  </div><!-- end class-card -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something more like this should work. Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0458dxb3/

You want to use classes throughout, but target your main "card" class, by going up the DOM with jQuery's 'closest' from `$(this)` (which is the element you clicked on) until jQuery finds it.

The "theory", if you will, is to find the 'card' element you want to work with (which contains the 'read more' button you clicked on), and then use jQuery's "find" method (this goes down the DOM) to work with all of the children you need to access. This will keep you inside that element and you won't access any of the other classes on the page.

**Obs**: You should use `class` instead of `id` on this case, because you should have one `element` for each `id`. If you have two `elements` with the same `id`, the selector (like in your exemple) picks the first one.

**Obs 2**: Another approach is assign an `id` value dynamically and randomly, but, on this case, it would be difficult and stressful.

**js**

```
$(".toggle").click(function() {
  var card = $(this).closest('.class-card');
  var toggleText = card.find('.toggle').text();
  if (toggleText == "Read More") {
    //Stuff to do when btn is in the read more state
    card.find(".toggle").text("Read Less");
    card.find(".text").slideDown();
  } else {
    //Stuff to do when btn is in the read less state
    card.find(".toggle").text("Read More");
    card.find(".text").slideUp();
  }
});
```

**html** fine, except needs some ids changed to classes.

```
<!-- CLASS CARD 1 -->
<!-- CLASS CARD 1 -->
<!-- CLASS CARD 1 -->
  <div class="class-card">
  <h2>Course Title</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse felis eros, iaculis vel sem sed, aliquam pretium nunc. Nulla luctus arcu est, sed fermentum quam aliquam nec.</p>
  <!-- NOTE: '#text' wraps the expandable stuff -->
  <span class="text">
      <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</li>
      </ul>
      <p><strong>Pick a Time:</strong></p>
      <a class="black-button" href="#">Monday 7/23 @ 1PM &ndash; 3PM</a>
      <a class="black-button" href="#">Wednesday 7/24 @ 12PM &ndash; 2PM</a>
  </span><!--end text -->

  <!-- '#toggle' triggers the JQuery function -->
  <a class="toggle">Read More</a>

  </div><!-- end class-card -->
```

Comment: For sure! Glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function you provide to `.click` will have an event object as the first parameter.
The .target property of that event object should be the individual item that was clicked.

So you could use something like:

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).whatever();  // Do whatever you need to do using e.target
});
```